# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS process stuck at tty login prompt

Tags: 16.04, login, tty

I just shutdown my device and on next launch instead of loading login screen it loads tty login screen [image: tty login screen]
If I enter wrong credential it says incorrect login attempt but when I enter correct credential it refreshes the screen to start-over like restarting a shell I have to again enter credential. Everytime I enter correct credential it redirects back to me again to login and even shell is not loading.

I have attempted to reboot to recovery mode to bump in to root shell but it asks for credential too before loading shell. 
Here I'm stuck at login screen it's neither launching shell nor desktop.

> PC Config: Dual boot: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have referred similar question like [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but None of them helped me.

However I am able to access file system of ubuntu in Windows

**Update:**

before redirecting to login screen below message prints for a milliseconds

```
Last login: Wed Dec 6 19:23:04 IST 2017 on tty1
/usr/bin/env: 'run-parts': No such file or directory
```

: [boot-report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/26123927/) generated by boot-repair

Comment: It could be a multitude of things, bad permissions on your home directory, or something wrong with your .profile file. Did you use Windows at any time to make changes to your Ubuntu OS? If you edit linux files via a Windows environment it can cause problems. I didn't quite understand why you weren't able to drop down to single user mode/recovery mode can you explain further why you cannot get into recovery mode?

Comment: I am able to launch recovery mode but unable to go in to root shell with same reason. I have to enter credential over and over again

Comment: Ok. Did you make any changes to the Ubuntu OS from your Windows OS? What happened before it stopped working, changes or software installation etc?

Comment: did `sudo apt-get upgrade`